# Implementation of `Class` like `String` Class

Tags: c#, function, interface, methods

I want to implement class i.e. we have String class in .Net. In that, if you check when we code....

C#:

```
String strString = "Value-12346- .";
String[] strArray = strString.Substring(0, strString.Length - 1).TrimEnd().ToUpper().Split("-".ToCharArray());
```

in this example if you check we are calling multiple functions of String Class, over each function i.e over `Substring` function `TrimEnd` is called and over `TrimEnd` `Split` function is called. I would like to implement similar. Please help me out.

Many Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure every method returns an object of the same type (or the type you want) and then you can call the methods on the object like that ( cascade or chain). Each of the above method in the string example returns a new string ( note that strings are immutable here ), so you can apply the string functions again and so on.

On a related note, see how Fluent Interface works. The C# example showing non-fluent and fluent API is a good example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

```
public IConfigurationFluent SetColor(string newColor)
        {
            this.color = newColor;
            return this;
        }
```

Comment: Let's emphasize this a bit more. As strings are immutable, each of the functions returns a NEW string object. One should be aware of this if working in a resource restricted environment like phones or embedded and such.

Answer (score 0):

As manojlds pointed out above, you achieve that by making your class' member methods return the type of their owner class. Now, in particular, the String's methods return a new string instance every time (instead of "modifying" the source and returning it), so you might want in your methods to create a deep copy of "this" and then made any changes to the new object and return it. Not only that, but the String class is immutable.

Sorry for being too detailed.